# Masking Certain Parts of Specific Records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way in SQL Server to mask only certain records for a given column based on a primary key value? I know the new Dynamic Data Masking function automatically masks the whole field that you select. Is there a way to just do certain records?

Answer (score 1):

If you control the T-SQL (like if you're dealing with views or a reporting system), then you're probably looking for a user-defined function. With UDFs, you can code your own logic into something like this:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_Mask(MySecretField) FROM dbo.tbl_PreciousData
```

(Having a little fun with the naming geeks there.)

Then, inside fn_Mask, you'd write your own logic to take MySecretField as your input (and you could pass in multiple fields if you like), and even look at the logged-in user's security information to decide whether or not to mask the data.

But danger, Will Robinson: [scalar UDFs make your query go serial](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx), as opposed to parallel. Between that, and the fact that people can still directly select MySecretField, this is only a solution for limited scenarios.